# set “child2, mygrid_2” values into “MyPanel, myGrid”

Tags: mysql, grid, wxpython, parent-child

i want to set values into myGrid Parent(MyPanel) from child2, but failed to do so, Please help and suggest as i m new in programming, Thanks in advance

```
import wx
import wx.grid
import MySQLdb

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.currentlySelectedCell = (0, 0)
        self.parent = parent
        self.myGrid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        self.myGrid.CreateGrid(8, 6)
        self.myGrid.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.child1 = MyDialog1(self)
        self.child2 = MyDialog2(self)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnChar(self, event):
        pro = self.myGrid.GetCellValue(0, 0)
        cnn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass",  "rms" )
        cursor=cnn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT product_name, supplier_name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%"+pro+"%'")         
        rows=cursor.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(rows)):
            for j in range(0,2):
                cell=rows[i]
                self.child1.grid_1.SetCellValue(i,j,str(cell[j]))                
        cnn.commit()
        cnn.close()      
        event.Skip()        
        self.child1.Show()
########################################################################
class MyDialog1(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__ (self, parent1):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, size=(350, 250), title="CHILD 1", style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)                       
        wx.Dialog.CenterOnScreen(self)
        self.parent = parent1        
        self.grid_1 = wx.grid.Grid(self)        
        self.but = wx.Button(self, -1, "Load")
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, self.click, self.grid_1)
        self.grid_1.CreateGrid(7, 2)
        self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(0, ("ProductName"))
        self.grid_1.SetColSize(0, 150)
        self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(4, ("Supplier Name"))
        self.grid_1.SetColSize(4, 165)       
        sizer_4 = wx.GridSizer(wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_ALL)
        sizer_4.Add(self.grid_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_4.Add(self.but, 1, wx.CENTER, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_4)       
        self.child2 = MyDialog2(self)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def click(self, event):
        pro1 = self.grid_1.GetCellValue(0, 0)
        cnn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass",  "rms" )
        cursor=cnn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT product_name, batch_no, qty, purchase_price, sale_price FROM purchase_item WHERE product_name LIKE '%"+pro1+"%'")         
        rows=cursor.fetchall()        
        for i in range(len(rows)):
            for j in range(0,5): 
                cell = rows[i]                
                self.child2.grid_2.SetCellValue(i,j,str(cell[j]))                
        cnn.commit()
        cnn.close()        
        event.Skip()       
        self.child2.Show()
########################################################################   
class MyDialog2(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, size=(650, 300), title="CHILD 2", style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)                       
        wx.Dialog.CenterOnScreen(self)
        self.parent = parent        
        self.grid_2 = wx.grid.Grid(self)               
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, self.click2, self.grid_2)
        self.grid_2.CreateGrid(7, 5)
        self.grid_2.SetColLabelValue(0, ("ProductName"))
        self.grid_2.SetColSize(0, 150)
        self.grid_2.SetColLabelValue(1, ("Batch No"))
        self.grid_2.SetColSize(1, 80)
        self.grid_2.SetColLabelValue(2, ("Stock"))
        self.grid_2.SetColSize(2, 80)
        self.grid_2.SetColLabelValue(3, ("Purchase Rate"))
        self.grid_2.SetColSize(3, 80)
        self.grid_2.SetColLabelValue(4, ("Sale Rate"))
        self.grid_2.SetColSize(4, 165)         
        sizer_4 = wx.GridSizer(wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_ALL)
        sizer_4.Add(self.grid_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_4)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def click2(self, event):
        for row in range(0,5):
            for col in range(0,5):
                val = self.grid_2.GetCellValue(0,5)
                self.parent.myGrid.SetCellValue(str(val)) # I want to show this Cell 
                                                   #Values in MyPanel Class myGrid value       
        event.Skip()
        self.Destroy()
        #self.Close()
```

Traceback here:

```
 """ >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sunil/GuiTest/Grid_project_New.py", line 96, in click2
    self.parent.myGrid.SetCellValue(str(val)) # I want to show this Cell Values in MyPanel Class myGrid value       
AttributeError: 'MyDialog1' object has no attribute 'myGrid'   """
```

rest of code:

```
########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show() 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question might be better received if you take the trouble to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't run your example to test it because I dont have MySQLDB. Yet this is irrelevant to your problem...

Comment: I can't run your example, even after stripping MySQLdb code: I get a wx error. What version of wx are you using? In order to debug this, I would start printing out the value of attributes of MyDialog2, to try to find out why self.parent appears to be MyDialog1 in click2, because I can't see how it gets that way just from reading the code.

Comment: i m using wx 2.8 version, as i said i m absolute new in programming, if there could be another way, then please suggest, "i want that when clicking on grid_2 cellvalue of MyDialog2 class set into myGrid of MyPanel class i.e parent,.... it any other possible way of doing so, please suggest, thanks !

Comment: (1). inserting value into cell of myGrid of MyPanel, open a new child1=MyDialog1 retrieving data from MySqlDB table "products" and set into grid_1,  (2). when clicking into mygrid_1, a new i.e child2 of Mydialog2 opens and retrieve data from another MySql Table i.e "purchase_item"and set into grid_2 of MyDialog2 and FINALLY         (3). click2 sets cell values into myGrid of MyPanel class i.e actual parent, in third step it gives """AttributeError: 'MyDialog1' object has no attribute 'myGrid'"""